# iOS How to access Library in CSS Url's?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova

I have multiple images that are fetched from an API and recorded like

```
Library/NoCloud/images/marble.png
```

In javascript-side, I used to display images using DOM elements and CSS properties using

```
<cover><img src="images/marble.png"/></cover>
```

However, now that I am using the Library folder (because it's forbidden to write in app bundle), I cannot access those images in the Library through CSS url directly. How to reference them in this case?

Comment: Check your console for error logs when you try to reference your images using CSS. How do you reference them? using `background-image: url(path/to/image/image.jpg);` ?

Comment: Yes exactly like that. I tried using the path I get by using window.resolveFileSystem.  But it appends it to the css path like  www/path/to/library/path/to/image/image.png

Comment: Open the image in a new window, copy the exact url, what happens if you put that url in the CSS? do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Yes I did have errors, while clearing that out I saw a typo at the beginning of the url! Thats why it did not load from root, but appended the path to www folder I think. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: Yes, it loads the images now perfectly. Setting the url correctly did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by setting the path directly. I get it from:

```
 window.resolveFileSystem(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dir){
     setCSSBackgroundWithPath(dir.nativeURL);
 });
```

In CSS, both

```
<img src="dir.nativeURL/path/to/image.png"/>
```

and

```
<cover style="background-image: url(dir.nativeURL/path/to/image.png)"></cover>
```

works ok.

Note: Actual setting of CSS is not handled this way, I left off the implementation details here just to say this works